# Pandas to_datetime function works differently depending on series order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, series

I am currently working on a project where I need to validate that some dates in a python dataframe are respecting a specific format such as `days[any divider]month[any divider]year`. I've decided to use [pandas.to_datetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) since it was solving my problems in a pretty nice way. Here's an example of what I've done:

```py
foo = pd.Series(['01-01-2023','JAN-01-2023'])
pd.to_datetime(foo,dayfirst=True,errors='coerce').notnull()
>>  0 True
    1 False
```

However, once I change the order of this series and uses 'JAN-01-2023' as the first element, here's what happens:

```py
foo = pd.Series(['JAN-01-2023','01-01-2023'])
pd.to_datetime(foo,dayfirst=True,errors='coerce').notnull()
>>  0 True
    1 True
```

My current workaround is not to use to_datetime, but `.apply` with custom validation function which performs for...in.. loop onto dataframe's column, however I've checked some performance issues using `.apply` since it iterates every row on the series.

I'm not sure this is some kind of misinterpretation about to_datetime documentation or if it's really a bug. I could not find any issue on pandas GitHub, neither here on stack overflow. Has anybody ever ran into this?

**System Settings:**
windows 10 x64;
python version 3.8.10;
pandas version pandas 2.0.3

Checked issues on stack overflow.
Checked issues on pandas Repository on GitHub
Checked to_datetime documentation

Comment: When I try your code I always get True.  The `pandas.to_datetime` documentation includes the warning: 

dayfirst=True is not strict, but will prefer to parse with day first.

Comment: I can replicate your result but get the following warning with the second option `1: UserWarning: Could not infer format, so each element will be parsed individually, falling back to dateutil. To ensure parsing is consistent and as-expected, please specify a format.`

Comment: I also get all True when I run your code. Consider using `dateutil.parser` instead, or simply write your own set of checks if you know which formats you will accept and which you will not.

Comment: this is because pandas cannot infer the correct format in the second version because it looks like a string...

Comment: I could not reproduce both cases with a True value. I understand both scenarios, whether it is converted (as Malcom pointed out, dayfirst is not strict) or not (as pointed out by D.L), since it looks like a string, but what does the order of the items have to do with the conversion anyway?
Also, my coworker could reproduce on his machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[pandas.to_datetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) will use the first string to discover the format.

```py
# Format %d-%m-%y (not valid for JAN-01-2023)
foo = pd.Series(['01-01-2023', 'JAN-01-2023'])
pd.to_datetime(foo, dayfirst=True, errors='coerce').notnull()

# Format %m-%d-%y (valid for both)
foo = pd.Series(['JAN-01-2023', '01-01-2023'])
pd.to_datetime(foo, dayfirst=True, errors='coerce').notnull()
```

If you will have multiple formats, you probably want to pass the parameter `format='mixed'`

```py
pd.to_datetime(foo, format='mixed', dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')
```

In cases where the date is ambiguous like `01-01-2023`, passing the parameter `dayfirst` as `True` will give priority to formats where day come first (there is also `yearfirst`).